# Inconsistent closing of questions

Tags: support, status-declined, closed-questions, reopen-request

Last year I posted the question "[How Often Should I Run ChkDsk?](https://superuser.com/questions/178578/how-often-should-i-run-chkdsk)" and the question received a decent amount of views and a handful of answers. Today, I asked the question "[Should I ever put my computer in sleep mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/404072/should-i-ever-put-my-computer-in-sleep-mode/404090#404090)", and it was voted down and closed. I would like clarification as to why the first question was not closed, but the second question was closed. To me, they are in the same class of question. One can argue that the ChkDsk question would also "likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". And since the ChkDsk question was not closed, I believe the second one should not have been closed either.

Comment: There is a significant difference in *quality* between the two.

Comment: Please explain. Also, couldn't it just been edited or ask for editing instead of closing the question, especially if it's relevant after all?

Comment: Your question was closed as `Not Constructive` by *a number of people*, so multiple people agree that it is NC. Definition of NC: `This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. See the FAQ for guidance on how to improve it.`. I agree. Your question isn't helpful, it's not well written, it's vague, it's overly broad.

Answer (score 5):

To start off, please note that question is **2 years old.** Our standards have changed a lot since then.

The problem with your question is that we cannot pick the answer for you - it varies for every user. You didn't tell us your use of the machine, how often you generally keep it powered on, or any supporting facts about the computer. With that, its **Not Constructive** - we cannot give a solid answer to it.

The question about `chkdsk` actually can be answered canonically, since `chkdsk` is only meant to be run at certain times, and there are actual Microsoft KB articles that have information on it. You appeared to do some research, mentioning the difference between older version of Windows and new. You're newer question did not say what you had tried at all.

With that, I think its fair to be seen that your question was worth closing.

Answer (score -5):

I will take the other side of this debate.  I think that closed questions should be reserved for SPAM, people trying to jerk things around, and totally inapproprite questions for any other locations on the web.

It still wouldnt change the fact that the Question is not what, or How you would ask at a Local BBQ around your friends,  It is more akin to something we might see TEXTED from a cell phone while your driving down the road :-)   So I can understand why there is little appretiation for it.

Because a question can be edited, you could do a better question, still.

You still have what I concider to be very adequite comments and answers, With the way the question was asked.   If you needed an "answer" from what I can see you got it.  If you needed more input on the question, and various opinions and experiences on standby , I would like to see that HERE.

I myself do not see anything wrong with layers of different peoples experiences and learnings, and leanings on a question.

Comment: No, the things you mentioned deserve deletion, not closure.